# Grunt Serve issues on Mac

Tags: gruntjs, npm, compass

steps:
npm install -g yo

npm install -g grunt

npm install -g bower

npm install -g generator-angular

mkdir storefront

cd storefront/

yo angular

grunt serve

---

`grunt serve` isn't working for me as seen below:

```
ME$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
    Warning: Couldn't find the `compass` binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


    Execution Time (2015-04-08 20:14:01 UTC)
    loading tasks    5ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 21%
    compass:server  18ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 75%
    Total 24ms Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-04-08 20:13:58 UTC)
wiredep:app        115ms  ▇▇▇▇ 4%
concurrent:server   2.6s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 95%
Total 2.8s
```

---

I tried two things:

1. `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`

that resulted in:

```
$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
Password:
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/through2 requires readable-stream@'~1.0.17' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.27-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build requires colors@'0.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/node_modules/stream-counter requires readable-stream@'~1.1.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/node_modules/readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.13-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
```

and

2. `npm install -g compass`

that resulted in:

```
ME$ npm install -g compass
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/node_modules/through2 requires readable-stream@'~1.0.17' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.0.27-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/phonegap-build requires colors@'0.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/node_modules/stream-counter requires readable-stream@'~1.1.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/connect/node_modules/multiparty/node_modules/readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.13-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/prompt/node_modules/winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
compass@0.1.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/compass
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Dumb questions first since this question can be interpreted multiple ways: Have you run "bower install" and "npm install" if your project requires them?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just tried grunt serve --force, which gave me a more specific error message...  Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

Comment: I also use the yeoman generator on mac but haven't seen this error. You might want to try running 'npm cache clean' in that folder which might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by setting logConcurrentOutput to false in my Gruntfile.

Go to app --> Gruntfile.js

Search for concurrent, and ensure your concurrent code for logConcurrentOutput looks like this:

```
 concurrent: {
  ionic: {
    tasks: [],
    options: {
      logConcurrentOutput: false
    }
  }
```